# How to see tables and column names in exact case which is created and not by default uppercase?

Tags: oracle, toad

In toad, whenever I create an object such as a table, If I name columns in PascalCase when it created if I open the table, then toad displays all the column names in uppercase.

Is there any option in toad which prevents this default behavior and let us see the object names in the exact case which we create them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That has nothing to do with TOAD.

[As documented in the manual](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/Database-Object-Names-and-Qualifiers.html#GUID-3C59E44A-5140-4BCA-B9E1-3039C8050C49) Oracle converts all non-quoted identifiers to uppercase.

If you really, really want to make your life a lot harder then it has to be, and really want to create mixed case identifiers, you have to quote them during creation:

```sql
create table "SomeTable" 
(
   "Id" integer not null primary key,
   "SomeColumn" varchar(100)
);
```

But I strongly recommend to **not** use quoted identifiers. They will create much more problems in the long run than they are worth it.